# Django GET request download from Dropbox

Tags: django, get, httprequest, dropbox

```
class FileDropboxDownloadView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = global_login_url

    def get(self, request, pk):
        # return self.head(self)

        # use the path to find the filename
        db_query_file = self.request.path
        # remove the trailing slash
        db_query_file = db_query_file[:-1]
        # regular expressions to remove the beginning
        db_query_file = re.sub('^(/)[\w]+(/)[\w]+', '', db_query_file)

        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(dropbox_token)
        return dbx.files_download(db_query_file, rev=None)
```

When I try this it only gives me the meta-data of the file, not the file itself. Is there a way to make it return the file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call files_download_to_file as pointed out on: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py

```
# Restore the local and Dropbox files to a certain revision
def restore(rev=None):
    # Restore the file on Dropbox to a certain revision
    print("Restoring " + BACKUPPATH + " to revision " + rev + " on Dropbox...")
    dbx.files_restore(BACKUPPATH, rev)

    # Download the specific revision of the file at BACKUPPATH to LOCALFILE
    print("Downloading current " + BACKUPPATH + " from Dropbox, overwriting " + LOCALFILE + "...")
dbx.files_download_to_file(LOCALFILE, BACKUPPATH, rev)
```